# Expected Error of OLS different from Zero

Tags: regression, least-squares, conditional-expectation

I am estimating a regression model for a dependent variable that could be grouped into 2 types based on characteristics that are not part of X. My out of sample forecasting errors are dependent on the regimes I am in. That is, when one group of the dependent variable has high values the model produces lower errors and vice versa. Is this an indication of a violation of the OLS assumptions or is there an obvious fix?

Comment: Why not add "group" to "X"?

Comment: I thought about that too. Is there some elegant way of showing that group should be in X in order for the OLS estimates to be 'correct'? Rather than just trial and error?

Comment: I don't know about "elegant" or "trial and error" here.  If you have information that is related to the dependent variable, why not include it in the independent variables?  There may be some reason in some situation, but, generally, I think you just include it.

Comment: totally agree, but I need to run this up the flagpole first before adding variables, so I thought maybe there is a mathematical proof to show that under these conditions the estimate is incorrect or something along those lines.